# Tool to merge .xml data

Tags: xml, code-coverage

Is there a tool that will merge data from multiple xmls with the same data structure.

Eg: coverage data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to do this with a simple bat file

```
@Echo On

TITLE APPEND FILES


 ECHO ^<root^> > C:\AppendedFile.xml 

 for %%f in (C:\works\file*.xml) do (

 type "%%f" >> C:\AppendedFile.xml         

 )


 ECHO ^</root^> >> C:\AppendedFile.xml 

 pause
```

Comment: That looks like it will just append one file to another (concatenation) it is not aggregating the results.

Comment: Yes, Shaun, i dont know the logic to concatenate it... should i add up the numbers etc... so this is what i found. Can a open cover report be directly added?

Comment: If the reports were generated from the same assemblies then you should just be able to sum the counts for each sequence point but if the saaemblies were not loaded and analysed in the same order then this may not work as the unique-ids assigned to a sequence point may not be the same between runs - in this case you would need to match on methodname and offset.